# Reorganize timestamps into drawers

Tags: org-mode

I just learned about the following org-mode option, which ensures **newly entered** timestamps end up in the LOGBOOK drawer:

```
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
```

How can I automatically move **existing** timestamps (which so far have been logged outside of the drawer) so that they all end up inside the drawer?

As an example, how to quickly go from:

```
** TODO Important task
SCHEDULED: <2018-04-23 Mon .+7d>
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2018-04-09 Mon 14:05]
CLOCK: [2018-04-09 Mon 14:02]--[2018-04-09 Mon 14:05] =>  0:03
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2018-03-26 Mon 09:21]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2018-03-19 Mon 13:15]
CLOCK: [2018-03-19 Mon 13:09]--[2018-03-19 Mon 13:15] =>  0:06
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2018-03-01 Thu 12:39]
CLOCK: [2018-02-26 Mon 08:43]--[2018-02-26 Mon 08:56] =>  0:13
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2018-01-18 Thu 08:20]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-11-13 mån 14:07]
CLOCK: [2017-11-13 mån 14:06]--[2017-11-13 mån 14:07] =>  0:01
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-10-23 mån 17:55]
CLOCK: [2017-10-23 mån 10:08]--[2017-10-23 mån 10:11] =>  0:03
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-10-02 mån 10:46]
CLOCK: [2017-10-02 mån 10:44]--[2017-10-02 mån 10:46] =>  0:02
```

To something like:

```
** TODO Important task
SCHEDULED: <2018-04-23 Mon .+7d>
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2018-04-09 Mon 14:02]--[2018-04-09 Mon 14:05] =>  0:03
CLOCK: [2018-03-19 Mon 13:09]--[2018-03-19 Mon 13:15] =>  0:06
CLOCK: [2018-02-26 Mon 08:43]--[2018-02-26 Mon 08:56] =>  0:13
CLOCK: [2017-11-13 mån 14:06]--[2017-11-13 mån 14:07] =>  0:01
CLOCK: [2017-10-23 mån 10:08]--[2017-10-23 mån 10:11] =>  0:03
CLOCK: [2017-10-02 mån 10:44]--[2017-10-02 mån 10:46] =>  0:02
:END:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-10-23 mån 17:55]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2017-10-02 mån 10:46]
[...]
```

Comment: Please provide a specific example of where your time-stamp(s) is/are that you want to move, and which drawer you wish to target (e.g., LOGBOOK), and what should happen if there are two times-tamps; e.g., DEADLINE and SCHEDULED.  Some people put time-stamps in a heading, and some people put time-stamps in the notes section.  So, as you see, including the drawer, there are at least five possible locations.

Comment: Good point. I updated my question.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found two answers. If the native solution fails, can you check the value of the variable `org-clock-into-drawer` (`C-h v org-clock-into-drawer`, mine is `t`) and the return value of the function `(org-clock-into-drawer)` (`M-: (org-clock-into-drawer)`, mine is `LOGBOOK`)?

Answer (score 2):

### Native solution

From the documentation of `org-clock-into-drawer` (see it with `C-h f org-clock-into-drawer`):

```
Non-nil when clocking info should be wrapped into a drawer.

When non-nil, clocking info will be inserted into the same drawer
as log notes (see variable ‘org-log-into-drawer’), if it exists,
or "LOGBOOK" otherwise.  If necessary, the drawer will be
created.

When an integer, the drawer is created only when the number of
clocking entries in an item reaches or exceeds this value.

When a string, it becomes the name of the drawer, ignoring the
log notes drawer altogether.
```

Therefore, after running `(setq org-clock-into-drawer t)` and clocking in on a headline, any lines under that headline that are a clock segment such as:

```
CLOCK: [2018-04-09 Mon 14:02]--[2018-04-09 Mon 14:05] =>  0:03
```

are first moved into a drawer, creating one if necessary and in reverse order that they appear, and the new clock time is added at the top.

### Solution in Python

I disliked the reverse order and am too unfamiliar with Emacs LISP to adapt the source code from function `org-clock-find-position` (lines 1508 onwards of `org-clock.el.gz` in my version). So I used Python 3.

The code below runs the doc-tests first and only if they all pass does it process the file. It also moves into the drawer any lines that are state changes:

```
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-07-23 Tue 23:11]
```

It keeps the order of appearance of lines that are clock segments or state changes. It creates a backup of the file before running it. I inspected the result manually and could not find any errors.

Save as `<name-of-script>`, then call with `python3 <name-of-script> -f <path-to-org-file>`.

```py
import argparse
import doctest
import os
import re
import shutil

DEFAULT_FILE = os.path.expanduser("~/org/gtd.org")
LOGBOOK_START = ":LOGBOOK:"
LOGBOOK_END = ":END:"

META_DATA_RE = "^( |\\t)*:?(CLOSED|DEADLINE|SCHEDULED|END|#+END):"
HEADLINE_RE = "[*]+ "

def find_end_of_metadata(lines):
    """Finds the last index of metadata in the array
    >>> lines = ['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-24 Tue 08:04 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-23 Mon 11:42]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '...', \
    ':END:', \
    'some comment']
    >>> find_end_of_metadata(lines) == len(lines) - 2
    True
    """

    if list != type(lines):
        raise ValueError("This function requires a list as input")

    num_lines = len(lines)
    for i in range(num_lines - 1, -1, -1):
        line = lines[i]
        if re.match(META_DATA_RE, line) or re.match(HEADLINE_RE, line):
            return i
    assert False, "Unable to find end of metadata!" + "\n".join(lines)

def process_headline(headline, logbook_start = LOGBOOK_START, logbook_end = LOGBOOK_END):
    """Processes the headline, creating a logbook drawer if needed, and
    moving state changes and clocks into the logbook drawer.
    >>> no_drawer_headline = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52'])
    >>> no_drawer_actual = process_headline(no_drawer_headline)
    >>> no_drawer_expected = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52', \
    ':END:'])
    >>> drawer_headline = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    ':END:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52'])
    >>> drawer_actual = process_headline(drawer_headline)
    >>> drawer_expected = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52', \
    ':END:'])
    >>> no_drawer_actual == no_drawer_expected
    True
    >>> drawer_actual == drawer_expected
    True
    """

    # Split by lines
    lines = re.split("\n|\r", headline)

    # Find the indices of all the lines that are a state change
    # and copy them over
    indices = []
    logbook_lines = []
    for iLine, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('- State') or line.startswith('CLOCK: '):
            indices.append(iLine)
            logbook_lines.append(line)

    if 0 == len(logbook_lines):
        return headline

    # Delete lines from original
    for iLine in reversed(indices):
        lines.pop(iLine)

    # Initialize new array to hold result
    processed_lines = []

    # Find index of logbook drawer, if any
    if logbook_start in lines:
        logbook_start_index = lines.index(logbook_start)
        logbook_end_index = lines.index(logbook_end, logbook_start_index)
    else:
        logbook_start_index = find_end_of_metadata(lines) + 1
        lines = lines[:logbook_start_index] + [logbook_start, logbook_end] + lines[logbook_start_index:]
        logbook_end_index = logbook_start_index + 1

    # Add clock lines in the logbook drawer
    return "\n".join(lines[:(logbook_start_index + 1)] + logbook_lines + lines[logbook_end_index:])

def split_headlines(s):
    """Splits the contents of an Org file by headline and keeps the delimiter that marks it.
    >>> contents = "\\n".join(['* Level 1', \
    '** TODO Level 2', \
    'comments', \
    '** Level 2'])
    >>> actual = split_headlines(contents)
    >>> expected = ['* Level 1', \
    '\\n'.join(['** TODO Level 2', 'comments']),
    '** Level 2']
    >>> actual == expected
    True
    """

    regex = re.compile("(\\n|\\r)" + HEADLINE_RE)
    matches = []
    prev_end = 0
    for match in regex.finditer(s):
        match_start = match.start()
        matches.append(s[prev_end:match.start()])

        prev_end = match_start
        if s[prev_end] in ['\n', '\r']:
            prev_end += 1

    if prev_end < len(s):
        matches.append(s[prev_end:])

    return matches

def process_file(filepath):
    """For the org file in the argument, moves the state changes and clock segments into drawers.
    """

    # Make a backup, just in case
    backup = filepath + "_backup"
    assert not os.path.exists(backup), "Backup file already exists!"
    shutil.copy(filepath, backup)
    assert os.path.exists(backup)

    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read(-1)

    with open(backup, "r") as f:
        backup_contents = f.read(-1)

    assert contents == backup_contents

    # Split by headlines
    headlines = split_headlines(contents)

    # Process each
    new_headlines = []
    count = 0
    for h in headlines:
        new_h = process_headline(h)
        new_headlines.append(new_h)

    # Write to file
    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(new_headlines))

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Process text in an Org file")
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", default=DEFAULT_FILE)

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():

    args = get_args()
    filepath = args.file

    process_file(filepath)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    doctests = doctest.testmod()
    assert 0 == doctests.failed, "Some doc-tests failed, will not run the script"
    main()
```

Cross-posted from [this other thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52800/how-to-log-all-state-changes-of-recurring-tasks-to-a-drawer-just-like-clock-segm/52810#52810) that deals with lines with state changes.

Comment: The solution as mentioned before the Python code just works.  `(setq org-clock-into-drawer "CLOCKING")` will create a drawer named "CLOCKING", and move all the previous "CLOCK" time ranges to this drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162031/3034580)

Summary:

```
(setq org-log-done t)
```

puts both clocking and state changes in the :LOGBOOK: drawer. Nice and tidy.