# How to log all state changes of recurring tasks to a drawer just like clock segments?

Tags: org-mode

I have a recurring task with multiple state changes:

```
* TODO Some task
SCHEDULED: <2019-09-23 Mon 08:00 ++1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-22 Sun 16:40]
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-09-23 Mon 16:42]--[2019-09-23 Mon 16:43] =>  0:01
:END:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-22 Sun 16:40]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 19:22]
```

How can I move the state changes at the bottom, `State "DONE"       from "TODO"`, to their own drawer, similar to the clock segments that are in their own drawer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to set `org-log-into-drawer` to `t`.  By default it is `nil`.
You can do this programmatically in your startup with something like

```
(customize-set-variable 'org-log-into-drawer t)
```

or:

```
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
```

Or, probably better, you can customize the variable (`M-x customize-variable RET org-log-into-drawer`).

Comment: This works for new state changes. Do you know how to move previous state changes to that drawer as well?

Comment: For those that were already inserted outside the drawer, I think you'd need to kill & yank (cut & paste) them manually into your desired location.  Were it me, I'd just move the `:END:` marker down below the last state change in each case.

Comment: Thanks! I was too lazy, wrote Python code to do that for me, and added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just mention the drawer, this worked for me.

`(setq org-log-into-drawer LOGBOOK)`

Comment: Isn't there a quote missing or something?

Comment: nope, that's it. also as mentioned in previous comments. Jus use the custumization interface through M-x

Comment: Running this code throws `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable LOGBOOK)`. The documentation of `org-log-into-drawer` shows that this solution is similar to that of @jeffkowalski: "The value of this variable should be the name of the drawer to use. LOGBOOK is proposed as the default drawer for this purpose, you can also set this to a string to define the drawer of your choice."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jeffkowalski answer, I add my Python code below to also move previous state changes into the `LOGBOOK` drawer. For clock lines, after running `(setq org-clock-into-drawer t)` and clocking in on a headline, any lines under that headline that are a clock segment are moved into that drawer along with the new clock time. But the same does not happen for state changes. I looked at the source code in lines 1508 onwards of `org-clock.el`:

```el
;; When a clock drawer needs to be created because of the
;; number of clock items or simply if it is missing, collect
;; all clocks in the section and wrap them within the drawer.
((if (wholenump org-clock-into-drawer)
  ...
```

I am too unfamiliar with Emacs LISP to adapt that code, so I used Python 3.

The code below runs the doc-tests first and only if they all pass does it process the file. It keeps the order of appearance of lines that are clock segments or state changes. It creates a backup of the file before running it. I inspected the result manually and could not find any errors.

Save as `<name-of-script>`, then call with `python3 <name-of-script> -f <path-to-org-file>`.

```py
import argparse
import doctest
import os
import re
import shutil

DEFAULT_FILE = os.path.expanduser("~/org/gtd.org")
LOGBOOK_START = ":LOGBOOK:"
LOGBOOK_END = ":END:"

META_DATA_RE = "^( |\\t)*:?(CLOSED|DEADLINE|SCHEDULED|END|#+END):"
HEADLINE_RE = "[*]+ "

def find_end_of_metadata(lines):
    """Finds the last index of metadata in the array
    >>> lines = ['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-24 Tue 08:04 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-23 Mon 11:42]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '...', \
    ':END:', \
    'some comment']
    >>> find_end_of_metadata(lines) == len(lines) - 2
    True
    """

    if list != type(lines):
        raise ValueError("This function requires a list as input")

    num_lines = len(lines)
    for i in range(num_lines - 1, -1, -1):
        line = lines[i]
        if re.match(META_DATA_RE, line) or re.match(HEADLINE_RE, line):
            return i
    assert False, "Unable to find end of metadata!" + "\n".join(lines)

def process_headline(headline, logbook_start = LOGBOOK_START, logbook_end = LOGBOOK_END):
    """Processes the headline, creating a logbook drawer if needed, and
    moving state changes and clocks into the logbook drawer.
    >>> no_drawer_headline = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52'])
    >>> no_drawer_actual = process_headline(no_drawer_headline)
    >>> no_drawer_expected = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52', \
    ':END:'])
    >>> drawer_headline = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    ':END:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52'])
    >>> drawer_actual = process_headline(drawer_headline)
    >>> drawer_expected = '\\n'.join(['** TODO task', \
    'SCHEDULED: <2019-09-19 Thu 21:00 ++1d>', \
    ':PROPERTIES:', \
    ':LAST_REPEAT: [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    ':END:', \
    ':LOGBOOK:', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-18 Wed 21:24]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-09-24 Tue 09:01]--[2019-09-24 Tue 09:41] =>  0:40', \
    '- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-09-17 Tue 12:52]', \
    'CLOCK: [2019-04-22 Mon 14:31]--[2019-04-22 Mon 15:23] =>  0:52', \
    ':END:'])
    >>> no_drawer_actual == no_drawer_expected
    True
    >>> drawer_actual == drawer_expected
    True
    """

    # Split by lines
    lines = re.split("\n|\r", headline)

    # Find the indices of all the lines that are a state change
    # and copy them over
    indices = []
    logbook_lines = []
    for iLine, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('- State') or line.startswith('CLOCK: '):
            indices.append(iLine)
            logbook_lines.append(line)

    if 0 == len(logbook_lines):
        return headline

    # Delete lines from original
    for iLine in reversed(indices):
        lines.pop(iLine)

    # Initialize new array to hold result
    processed_lines = []

    # Find index of logbook drawer, if any
    if logbook_start in lines:
        logbook_start_index = lines.index(logbook_start)
        logbook_end_index = lines.index(logbook_end, logbook_start_index)
    else:
        logbook_start_index = find_end_of_metadata(lines) + 1
        lines = lines[:logbook_start_index] + [logbook_start, logbook_end] + lines[logbook_start_index:]
        logbook_end_index = logbook_start_index + 1

    # Add clock lines in the logbook drawer
    return "\n".join(lines[:(logbook_start_index + 1)] + logbook_lines + lines[logbook_end_index:])

def split_headlines(s):
    """Splits the contents of an Org file by headline and keeps the delimiter that marks it.
    >>> contents = "\\n".join(['* Level 1', \
    '** TODO Level 2', \
    'comments', \
    '** Level 2'])
    >>> actual = split_headlines(contents)
    >>> expected = ['* Level 1', \
    '\\n'.join(['** TODO Level 2', 'comments']),
    '** Level 2']
    >>> actual == expected
    True
    """

    regex = re.compile("(\\n|\\r)" + HEADLINE_RE)
    matches = []
    prev_end = 0
    for match in regex.finditer(s):
        match_start = match.start()
        matches.append(s[prev_end:match.start()])

        prev_end = match_start
        if s[prev_end] in ['\n', '\r']:
            prev_end += 1

    if prev_end < len(s):
        matches.append(s[prev_end:])

    return matches

def process_file(filepath):
    """For the org file in the argument, moves the state changes and clock segments into drawers.
    """

    # Make a backup, just in case
    backup = filepath + "_backup"
    assert not os.path.exists(backup), "Backup file already exists!"
    shutil.copy(filepath, backup)
    assert os.path.exists(backup)

    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read(-1)

    with open(backup, "r") as f:
        backup_contents = f.read(-1)

    assert contents == backup_contents

    # Split by headlines
    headlines = split_headlines(contents)

    # Process each
    new_headlines = []
    count = 0
    for h in headlines:
        new_h = process_headline(h)
        new_headlines.append(new_h)

    # Write to file
    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(new_headlines))

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Process text in an Org file")
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", default=DEFAULT_FILE)

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():

    args = get_args()
    filepath = args.file

    process_file(filepath)

if "__main__" == __name__:
    doctests = doctest.testmod()
    assert 0 == doctests.failed, "Some doc-tests failed, will not run the script"
    main()
```

Cross-posted to [this other thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41099/reorganize-timestamps-into-drawers/52820#52820) that dealt with the same problem with lines with clock segments (such as `CLOCK: [2019-07-17 Wed 14:54]--[2019-07-17 Wed 15:00] =>  0:06`).